# HDFS: Removing data node directory of only one node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hdp

We have a Hadoop cluster (HDP 3.1.4 with Ambari 2.7) containing 3 data nodes: data1, data2, data3 with following HDFS disks and mountpoints:

- host data[1-2]

  - /dev/sdb -> /mnt/datadisk1
  - /dev/sdc -> /mnt/datadisk2
  - /dev/sdd -> /mnt/datadisk3
- host data3

  - /dev/sdb -> /mnt/datadisk1
  - /dev/sdc -> /mnt/datadisk2

During cluster setup we set `dfs.datanode.data.dir` to value `/mnt/datadisk1,/mnt/datadisk2,/mnt/datadisk3`. Now we saw, that our root partition (`/`) on data3 node runs full, because the mount point /mnt/datadisk3 does not exist and therefore the (HDFS) data is stored on the root partition, instead of being ignored.

Is there a way to remove this wrong path (`data3 : /mnt/datadisk3`) somehow, without editing the config files directly on OS (we want to use Ambari)?

Answer (score 0):

@D.Muller you should be able to edit the paths in ambari.  During setup, ambari will try to add multiple paths to the directory listing.  Your paths need to be consistent across all the nodes.  This is likely where things got confused for you when a path was missing on a single node.  If you login to ambari and remove the non-existent disk, you should be able to fix this issue.